# Get driving distance betwwen two points

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

hi all need help on this. I am using below link to get direction: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=49.75332,6.50322&destination=49.71482,6.49944&mode=walking&sensor=false

wheb i hit above url in browser then i get xml response, can anyone tell me how to fetch shortest distance from that response(XML). i need distance only, not direction. plz suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by shortest distanace? Do you want to sum up the distance of all steps?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at response, I see that every step element has got

```
<distance>
<value>490</value>
<text>0.5 km</text>
</distance>
```

distance element, which gives you value and text, 490 seems to me 490 meters, So you can just sum up all the distance value to get you distance in meters and convert them to whichever scale you want.

Comment: I found total distance in XML